# Остановка потоков c помощью ExecutorService::shutdown

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

Есть поток:

```
public class Cooki implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {

            System.out.println("шаг");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Допустим я через экзекутор запущу три потока, как мне их остановить?

```
public void start () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        pool.submit(new Cooki (this.board, "Cooki - " + i));
    }
}


public void close() {
    pool.shutdown();
    while (!pool.isTerminated()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Таким образом, завершить не удалось, т.к. потоки по команде `shutdown()` не погасли и метод `isTerminated()` возвращает `false`, так как мне грамотно остановить потоки?

Comment: и как работает метод shutdown? я не нашёл его реализацию он прерывание запрашивает?

Comment: Посмотреть реализацию можно в IDE - например в IntelliJ IDEA наводите курсор на метод и нажимаете Ctrl+F.

Comment: я не нашёл там тупо метод  в интерфейсе, я не нашёл как он реализован

Comment: @AlexMur создать в вашем потоке некое поле `boolean stopped`. и замените `Thread.interrupted()` на `stopped`. Когда вы выставите `stopped=true` метод `run` отработает и поток завершиться (может через время некоторое). В интернете сейчас полно именно таких примеров что бы остановить другой поток.

Comment: так а как потом достучаться до пула к каждому потоку?

Comment: @AlexMur в цикле. Что за пул такой где нельзя получить список потоков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых [`ExecutorService::shutdown`](http://til/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown--) не прерывает потоки,

> Вызывает упорядоченное завершение работы, в котором *выполняются* ранее
>   поставленные задачи, но новые задачи не будут приняты.

для того чтобы потоки *прерывались* надо использовать [`ExecutorService::shutdownNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow--):

> Пытается остановить все активные задачи, приостанавливает
>   обработку ожидающих задач и возвращает список задач, ожидающих
>   выполнения. Эти задачи выгружаются (удаляются) из очереди задач после
>   возврата из этого метода.
>
> Этот метод не дожидается, что выполнение задач прекратится. Используйте
>   функцию ожидания [`ExecutorService::awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), чтобы сделать это.
>
> Нет никаких гарантий, кроме попыток применения максимального усилия прекратить
>   обработку, активно выполняющую задачи. Эта реализация отменяет задачи
>   через [`Thread::interrupt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--), поэтому любая задача, которая не отвечает
>   на прерывания, *никогда* не может завершиться.

---

Во вторых, если использовать последнее, то будет выскакивать стэктрейс, а цикл будет продолжаться поскольку `Thread.interrupted()` будет всегда возвращать `false`. Поэтому надо поменять условие выхода из цикла, так чтобы можно было определить в каком случае поток будет заканчивать работу.

```
boolean interrupted = false;

while (!interrupted) {
  System.out.println(s+ " шаг");
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    interrupted = true;
    System.out.println(s+ " interrupted ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Здесь можно добавить, что используя апи нельзя *остановить* потоки, но их можно прервать вышеуказанным способом.

Answer (score 0):

В описании метода [ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown--) написано, что после его вызова пул перестаёт принимать новые задачи, но не прекращает выполнения уже добавленных.