# Прерывание потока ввода

Tags: java

Допустим есть у меня отдельный поток который в цикле while ожидает ответ от сервера, например:

```
while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    // InputStream.read()
    // Какие-то действия
}
```

И допустим я из вне хочу прервать этот поток командой `Thread.interrupt()`. Тогда, как я понимаю, поток не прервется до тех пор, пока он не примет сообщение, не обработает его, и уже возвращаясь к условию цикла не прервется. Как прервать поток ввода, не дожидаясь ответа?

Comment: вообще это зависит от реализации `InputStream`, напр. для сокетов единственный документированный и надежно работающий способ прервать `read` - закрыть сокет.

Comment: В многопоточной среде надо всегда искать разумный выход из потока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java реализация потоков зависит от реализации JVM, а именно:

1. Вам не повезло и JVM реализует не преемптивную многопоточность - тогда да, пока не будет прочитан кусок - ничего не произойдет
2. Вам повезло и JVM реализует [преемптивную](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) многопоточность, тогда неважно в каком состоянии находится поток - будет выкинуто исключение `InterruptedException`

Скорее всего вам повезет, потому что в современных версиях Windows/Linux JVM использует механизм многопоточности предоставляемый ОСом, а там в Windows/Linux нормальная многопоточность с квантованием процессорного времени и проч. бантиками.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтоб тормознуть поток, надо в нем установить флаг interrupted в true, а в самом потоке мониторить этот флаг, и если он равен true, выбросить исключение InterruptedException.

Посмотрите здесь [Oracle tutorials interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Comment: Это не работает в работающих потоках

Comment: Вы не могли бы привести пример или ссылку на основании чего вы так решили?

Comment: Можешь почитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/875895/204920), но это трудно понять новичку.

Comment: По той ссылке написано именно то, что я и имел ввиду

Comment: По той ссылке написано именно то, что я и имел ввиду когда написал, что в потоке надо мониторить значение флага interrupted. А значение этого флага меняется из другого потока. Никаких противоречий не заметил.

Comment: Да, как раз я писал о том что это невозможно, но как я сказал, бесполезно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89451/discussion-between-z-john-and-roman-c).