# Как корректно остановить приложение с ThreadPoolExecutor при SIGTERM?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть приложение с пулом потоков.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadPoolSize, threadPoolSize,0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(threadPoolSize));

registerShutdownHook(executor);
        while (!executor.isShutdown()) {
                startExecutor(isOrderBy, isCheckOldChanges);
                if (countIterations == 0) isCheckOldChanges = false;
                countIterations++;
        }
...
System.out.println("Application was stop!");
}

private static void startExecutor(boolean isOrderBy, boolean isCheckOldChanges) {
        for (EntityModel model : allModels.values()) {
            if (executor.isShutdown()) {
                return;
            } else {
                Runnable worker = new ProducerThread(isOrderBy, isCheckOldChanges, model);
                if (executor.getQueue().remainingCapacity()==1){
                    while (executor.getQueue().remainingCapacity()==1){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                executor.execute(worker);
            }

        }
    }

private static void registerShutdownHook(ExecutorService executor) {
        final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                executor.shutdown();
                mainThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error(e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }));
    }
```

При остановке приложения выбрасывает:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
>   com.kafkaproducer.ProducerThread@57175e74 rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7bb58ca3[Shutting down, pool
>   size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks =
>   35]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
>     at com.ApplicationRun.startExecutor(ApplicationRun.java:101)    at
>   com.ApplicationRun.main(ApplicationRun.java:77)

Как сделать корректную остановку приложения?

Comment: Читай здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/875895/204920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью

> new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy().

А именно:

```
ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                threadPoolSize,
                threadPoolSize,
                0L,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(threadPoolSize),
                new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()
        );
        registerShutdownHook(executor);
```

Не уверен на 100%, что это именно то решение, но помогло.